# How to deserialize JSON object similar to array of different object TYPES?

Tags: .net, json, json.net

I have got json:

```
{
  "_embedded": {
    "users": {
      "1688416": {
        "id": 1688416,
        "name": "test"
      },
      "1688395": {
        "id": 1688395,
        "name": "test",

      },
      "1625614": {
        "id": 1625614,
        "name": "test"      
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I should deserialize it by Newtonsoft.JSON library, but i can't undestand how to?? Object in "users" object can change, and "users" - is not array.

I can just JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(myobject) and take all fields by indexes, but it's stupidly, and i want to deserialize this json to normal object. How to?

---

UPDATE: code that i use

```
T is User

public class Response<T>
    {     
        [JsonProperty("_embedded", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public EmbeddedContent<T> EmbeddedContent { get; set; }
    }

    public class EmbeddedContent<T>
    {
        [JsonPropertyNameBasedOnItemClass]
        public List<T> Items { get; set; }
    }

public class User{
    public int id{get;set;}
    public string name {get;set;}
}

JsonPropertyNameBasedOnItemClass - work like JsonProperty("users")
```

and try deserialize:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response<User>>(...)
```

Comment: what code are you using at the moment?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the dictionary instead of the list

For example:

```
public class EmbeddedContent<T>
{
    [JsonProperty("users")]
    public Dictionary<string, T> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Then refer to user by ID

```
var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response<User>>(json);
var user = response.EmbeddedContent.Items["1688416"];
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end, i found this solution:

```
var p = JObject.Parse(rawJson).SelectToken("_embedded.users").Children().Select(t => t.First.ToObject<User>());
```